# Use of ifelse after pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to apply one of two functions to elements of vector. Choice of which function to use is made based on vector's values.

To be specific: imagine you want to convert years coded with two digits (like '07' for '2007' and '85' for '1985') to four digits, assuming that all the dates are between 1919 and 2018.

So, you have to add 1900 to numbers larger than 18 and add 2000 to other numbers.

Now I want to do that with `%>%` operator (to be able to use it inside `mutate` statment in future).

This one:

```
c(18,20,21,15) %>% ifelse(.>18, .+1900, .+2000)
```

produces an error:

```
Error in ifelse(., . > 18, . + 1900, . + 2000) : unused argument (. + 2000)
```

I even understand why: `%>%` forces vector `c(18,20,21,15)` to be used as first argument of `ifelse`.

I have a workaround using anonymous function:

```
c(18,20,21,15) %>% (function(x) ifelse(x>18, x+1900, x+2000))
[1] 2018 1920 1921 2015
```

Can you suggest anything to avoid them (them = anonymous functions)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution works fine if you add curly braces:

```
c(18,20,21,15) %>% {ifelse(.>18, .+1900, .+2000)}
# [1] 2018 1920 1921 2015
```

You could also do this to avoid the `{}`:

```
c(18,20,21,15) %>% `+`(1900+100*(.<=18))
```

Or with `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
c(18,20,21,15) %>% add(1900+100*(.<=18))
```

keeping your `ifelse`:

```
c(18,20,21,15) %>% add(ifelse(.>18,1900,2000))
```

Comment: Moody, your advice is quite useful and generalized. I am looking for the answer for the very problem, and comes yours. many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the standard pipe behavior : the left element as a whole is used as the first argument of the function to the right (there is no vectorization here).

Here's a solution with `purrr::map_dbl` :

```
purrr::map_dbl(c(18,20,21,15), ~  ifelse(.>18, .+1900, .+2000))
[1] 2018 1920 1921 2015
```

If you want to use it with {dplyr}, I strongly suggest you switch to `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date = c(18,20,21,15))
df %>% mutate(new_date = case_when(date > 18 ~ date + 1900, 
                                   TRUE ~ date + 2000))
  date new_date
1   18     2018
2   20     1920
3   21     1921
4   15     2015
```

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I need. Thanks!